# Count instances of HttpApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpapplication

we are expecting in our ASP.NET-Application some serious perfomance problems and now we are investigating the problem.
It seems to us reasonable that the problem is related to current number of HttpApplications.
Is there a way to count these with perfom?

Comment: It is not reasonable to start pointing to something without any evidence. You need to first check what is creating the bottle neck and then go for resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In perfom is a peformance counter called "pipeline-instances" under asp.net applications, that can be used for counting the active HttpApplications.

Comment: Ok. But is that the source for the issue. If so, how did you solve it?